# Java - JFileChooser Network Dir User/Password prompt

Tags: java, applet, jfilechooser

I have a problem with a Java applet.  I implemented an applet that starts a `JFileChooser` dialog to choose a directory.

This directory is given back to a web application which started the Java applet.
In the local file system this works very well. But when I select a network computer
which needs an authentication via user / password the dialog doesn't shows this
prompt.

When I navigate in the Windows Explorer to this network computer the prompt is shown.

Do you have a hint to solve this? If there is another implementation like `JFileChooser`
which is able to do that it would be OK, too.

Comment: Note that 'prompt' has **2** 'p's.  As to 'another implementation', I'm not sure if it will do any better, but you might experiment with the code of [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).